# How to hide MySQL database credentials from the user itself and other exterior means?

Tags: mysql, security, passwords, password-protection

I have a Java Swing desktop program that connects to a MySQL online database only to receive data, but I am concerned about the security of my implementation: hard coding passwords would be a bad mistake and storing to an exterior file won't do either, since the user/other unwanted means can still access the password if he/she's sly enough.

What can I do?

Comment: *"How to hide MySQL database credentials from the user itself and other exterior means?"*  Don't hardcode/compile the MySQL user/password in the application as Java can be decompiled so yes that is a bad idea. Make a webservice (JSP or a other language) / socket server and "expose" the database through a protocol protected with a API key/application signup/client certificat of some kind..

Comment: Do you have any kind of examples as to how this could be done? I am new to all this.

Comment: *"Do you have any kind of examples as to how this could be done? I am new to all this."* These kind of questions are not really [ontopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here to ask external resources the question is also very broad to be answerd..  *"I am new to all this"* i would suggest reseaching what i said..

Comment: But here are some research links ... Java [JSP](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagy.html) and Java [sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html)